# SSL FAIL Mac to Security update 2015-004

Tags: ssl

After upgrading my Mac to Security update 2015-004 I started experiencing issues on website that use Thawte SSL certificate and with mandrillapp SMTP which as well use Thawte certificate.

I'm running up to date OS X Mavericks 10.9.5

[image]

Comment: Please don't keep cross-posting to every SE site you can think of. I was going to inline the image for you til I discovered this is the 3rd post of the same question.

Comment: Hi Tetsujin,
I'm very sorry and apologise for this, but had no choice since I didn't know where to post it correctly and was suggested to post it here on Super User to find the solution.

Could you edit the post for me or I need to close all three and open a new question here on Super User? If so how I can close the other two questions?

Comment: There should be a delete button directly under your post. I've inlined the image for you on here.